# Rotate coplanar 3D points to XY

Tags: rotation, matrix

I have a set of 3D points. All these points are on the same plane. I have the normal of the plane.

Now I need to rotate them in such a way that the Z value of all these points become zero. (that is, 3D to XY plane)

I have Googled a lot. I got very few results and most of them are very much mathematical. Few are about projection and few are with solution with OpenGL APIs.

I have seen this solution:
[Rotating 3d plane to XY plane](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/48095/rotating-3d-plane-to-xy-plane)

Based on this, I have implemented something like this:

```
public static List<Vector3D> RotateCoplanar3DPointsToXY(IList<Vector3D> points, Vector3D planeNormal)
        {
            var zAxis = new Vector3D(0, 0, 1);
            var rotationAxis = zAxis.Cross(planeNormal);
            rotationAxis.Normalize();
            var rotationAngle = (float)Math.Acos(zAxis.Dot(planeNormal));
            var matrix = Matrix4x4.FromAngleAxis(rotationAngle, rotationAxis);
            var newPoints = new List<Vector3D>();
            for (var i = 0; i < points.Count; i++)
            {
                var p = points[i];
                var newPoint = p.Transform(matrix);
                newPoints.Add(newPoint);
            }
            return newPoints;
        }
```

But this implementation is not working.

I have another implementation below based on @Bálint's comment. This is also not working.

```
public static Vector3D Cross(Vector3D a, Vector3D b)
        {
            return new Vector3D(
                a.Y * b.Z - a.Z * b.Y,
                a.Z * b.X - a.X * b.Z,
                a.X * b.Y - a.Y * b.X);
        }

        public static Matrix4x4 GetMatrixForRotatingCoplanar3DPointsToXY(Vector3D planeNormal)
        {
            var Z_NORMAL = new Vector3D(1, 0, 0);
            var d = planeNormal;
            var u = Z_NORMAL;

            var r = Cross(d, u);
            var t = Cross(r, d);
            var matrix = new Matrix4x4(
             r.X, t.X, d.X, 0,
             r.Y, t.Y, d.Y, 0,
             r.Z, t.Z, d.Z, 0,
             0, 0, 0, 1);

            return matrix;
        }
```

Comment: At first glance it looks ok. Are you getting wrong results? If so, what results are you getting? Otherwise, please clarify the problem.

Comment: I think, it is working fine after checking a condition like

if(planeNormal==zAxis)
{
   return new List<Vector3D>(points);
}

Comment: Hi @Bálint, Thanks for your solution. I have implemented your suggestion. Somewhere I am wrong. I have updated the question with your answer. Can you please look into this?

Comment: "not working" is never enough information to diagnose a specific problem. Always be sure to include the exact symptoms you're observing, like a test case for which the output differs from the desired output.

Answer (score 1):

Doing this requires high-level mathematics (college/university), so it's no wonder those are the only solutions you found. If you know how matrices work, it's pretty simple.

I already described how you can get a rotation matrix from a normal in [this post](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/173679/rotate-mesh-to-normal/173681#173681). Your problem is the exact inverse of this: instead of going from points in the XY plane to a rotated version, you need to go from the rotated version back to the XY plane. To do this, you need the **inverse** of the rotation matrix.

Thankfully, it's pretty simple to do that with rotation matrices, since to inverse one, you just need to transpose it. There should be a method for it in your library of choice, but if there isn't one, it's simply swapping the values out in the following way:

$$\begin{bmatrix}
a & b & c & d\\ 
e & f & g & h\\ 
i & j & k & l\\ 
m & n & o & p
\end{bmatrix}\rightarrow \begin{bmatrix}
a & e & i & m\\ 
b & f & j & n\\ 
c & g & k & o\\ 
d & h & l &p 
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Now just multiply every point with this matrix and you'll transform them in the XY plane.